# How to add conditions while updating mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the below code i want to update secondary phone number only if 10 digit number is passed from web form else i would like to use the phone number already inserted to secondary phone number during insert operation.

Can some one help me to correct the below code to achieve a conditional db update?

```
hotelModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "name": req.body['hotelName'], "contact.postalCode": parseInt(req.body['postalCode']) },
        {
        $set: {

            "contact.primaryContactNumber" : parseInt(req.body['primaryContactNumber']),
            if (req.body['secondaryContactNumber'].toString().trim().length == 10) {
                    "hotelSchema.contact.secondaryContactNumber: : parseInt(req.body['secondaryContactNumber'])
            }else{
                "contact.primaryContactNumber" : //How to add existing Secondary phone number?
            }           

        }
    }, { new: true },
    function (err, doc) {}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. What do you want to happen if the user doesn't input a valid number? You say, 'else i would like to use the phone number already inserted to secondary phone number during insert operation', but that sounds like `contact.secondaryContactNumber` already exists, and there would be no need to change anything.

Comment: Let me make my question simple.How do i skip the the updation of secondaryContactNumber when req.body['secondaryContactNumber'] is passed as null from web ui.In  GUI secondaryContactNumber is an optional field.It's up to a user whether he wants to update it or not.So i need to write the update logic in such a way that if user has provided secondary phone number in GUI then update it else just skip the secondary phone number updation.Hope this clarifies your query

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to update `contact.secondaryContactNumber` if the user has provided a valid phone number, otherwise you want `contact.secondaryContactNumber` to be unchanged. If so, just remove the `else` clause. You don't need to explicitly tell it to do something because by default it will do nothing, and that's what you want.

```
hotelModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "name": req.body['hotelName'], "contact.postalCode": parseInt(req.body['postalCode']) },
        {
        $set: {

            "contact.primaryContactNumber" : parseInt(req.body['primaryContactNumber']),
            if (req.body['secondaryContactNumber'].toString().trim().length == 10) {
                    "hotelSchema.contact.secondaryContactNumber: : parseInt(req.body['secondaryContactNumber'])
            }     
        }
    }, { new: true },
    function (err, doc) {}
```

Comment: if (req.body['secondaryContactNumber'].toString().trim().length == 10) { is giving me syntax error.